# i want 4 flipbox in one row but in my code is just showing 1

Tags: html, css, web, 3d, flip

Guys, I hope you are all fine, Guys am facing a problem actually I have a CSS flip box code but in this code, it's just showing 1 flip box in one row I want 4 flip boxes in one row how can I do this please help me Thanks.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="box">
        <div class="front"></div>
        <div class="back"></div>
    </div>

CSS:
.box {
    position: inherit;
    top: calc(50% - 200px);
    left: calc(50% - 150px);
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 2s;
    transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(00deg);
}
.box:hover {
    transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(180deg);
}
.box:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(moon-side.jpg);
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateX(-25px);
    transform-origin: left;
}
.box .front {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(moon.jpg);
    transform: translateZ(25px);
}

.box .back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(moon.jpg);
    transform: translateZ(-25px) rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add display: inline-block; to your .box.  And you can make 4 instances of your flip box in the HTML.  Also your heights were a little weird, so this might be what you want?

```css
.box {
    position: inherit;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 2s;
    transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(00deg);
    display: inline-block;
    float: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
.box:hover {
    transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(180deg);
}
.box:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(moon-side.jpg);
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateX(-25px);
    transform-origin: left;
}
.box .front {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(moon.jpg);
    transform: translateZ(25px);
}

.box .back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(moon.jpg);
    transform: translateZ(-25px) rotateY(180deg);
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="box">
        <div class="front">hello front</div>
        <div class="back">hello back</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
        <div class="front">hello front</div>
        <div class="back">hello back</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
        <div class="front">hello front</div>
        <div class="back">hello back</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
        <div class="front">hello front</div>
        <div class="back">hello back</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, bro its working brother how can I align in the center I mean 4 flip box center in the page

Comment: You need to make a container div for all 4 instances, then text align it to the center. I updated my code, please look.

Comment: no brother there is a problem I cant change flip box image I want a unique image on each flip box how to do that

Comment: Just change where I typed "hello front" and "hello back" with an HTML image source. See what I did here https://jsfiddle.net/52kgvjsf/

Comment: Thanks, bro for the help Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem.  Good luck with your project.